# Is there a short hand for if(s != null && !s.isEmpty())

Tags: java

There are many `!= null` s and `!= null && !s.isEmpty()`

Like this:

```
if(sidebar.getModel() != null && !sidebar.getModel().isEmpty()) { ... }
```

In our code. Too many that it looks not really good. Is there a short hand for this null check. Which Java library provides extensive support for such shorthand functions while does not need that much dependency on other java artifacts?

Like `if(notNull(s))` or `if(notEmpty(s))` which checks for not null and not empty altogether. Something like this.

Comment: why not write your own peice of trivial code?

Comment: You can write some generic method ;)

Comment: If these sort of checks are everywhere in your code, you might benefit from reading http://stackoverflow.com/questions/271526/avoiding-null-statements-in-java?rq=1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For `String` class there is `StringUtils.isEmpty(String value)` in `apache-commons-lang3`. For other types you can create your own static method and use it via `static import`.

Comment: Also for strings: "".equals(inputString) will do both a null check and an empty check.

Comment: @PieterDeBie but it returns false if String is null

Comment: @PieterDeBie what? and if `"".equals("")` return `true`, while it is really empty value

Comment: Indeed, I was wrong (I don't use that construction too much since i hate yoda statements). You can use it to check for strings without having to worry for null strings.

Answer (score 1):

Apache [commons-lang](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/javadocs/api-2.6/org/apache/commons/lang/StringUtils.html)

Checks if a String is not empty (""), not null and not whitespace only.

```
StringUtils.isNotBlank(null)      = false
StringUtils.isNotBlank("")        = false
StringUtils.isNotBlank(" ")       = false
StringUtils.isNotBlank("bob")     = true
StringUtils.isNotBlank("  bob  ") = true
```

Parameters:
str - the String to check, may be null

Returns:
true if the String is not empty and not null and not whitespace

Answer (score 0):

From ***Java 1.7*** you can use utility class `Objects`:

> Checks that the specified object reference is not null. This method is designed primarily for doing parameter validation in methods and constructors, as demonstrated below:

```
 public Foo(Bar bar) {
     this.bar = Objects.requireNonNull(bar);
 }
```

***Useful links***:

- [requireNonNull(T
  obj)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Objects.html#requireNonNull(T))
- [requireNonNull(T obj, String
  message)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Objects.html#requireNonNull(T,%20java.lang.String))

**UPDATE:**

For avoiding `NullPointerException` ***Java 1.8*** has some special class [Optional](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Optional.html).

Working with this class will be smt as follows:

```
    String contents = new String(Files.readAllBytes(Paths.get(Test.ALICE_PATH)), StandardCharsets.UTF_8);
    List<String> wordList = Arrays.asList(contents.split("[\\P{L}]+"));

    Optional<String> optionalValue = wordList.stream().filter(s -> s.contains("red")).findFirst();
    optionalValue.ifPresent(s -> System.out.println(s + " contains red"));

    Set<String> results = new HashSet<>();
    optionalValue.ifPresent(results::add);
    Optional<Boolean> added = optionalValue.map(results::add);

    System.out.println(added);
    //
    Optional<String> optionalString = Optional.empty();
    String result = optionalString.orElse("N/A");
    System.out.println("result: " + result);

    result = optionalString.orElseGet(() -> System.getProperty("user.dir"));
    System.out.println("result: " + result);
```

Comment: It is very bad decision: it will throw `NullPointerException` if value is null. Not what really QA wants

Comment: This will throw an exception if the object is null. That's not what the questioner wants. It seems that these methods should be used for validation of parameters.